# How to parse varied string dates

Tags: ios, xcode, nsdate, nsxmlparser, nsdateformatter

in my app im using the NSXMLParser to parse feeds.
i have a pubDate as well but in many varied string date format:

```
 1. 2013-04-17T12:00:24
 2. Wed, 17 Apr 2013 10:15 +0300
 3. Wed, 17 Apr 2013 11:07:01 +0200
 4. 11/04/2013 18:10:10
```

here's my code:

```
    NSDateFormatter *inputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    assert(inputFormatter != nil);
    NSLocale *loacle = [[NSLocale alloc]initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
    assert(loacle != nil);

    [inputFormatter setLocale:loacle];
    [inputFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];

    [inputFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

   NSString *dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",currentPubDate];
   NSDate *inputDate = [inputFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

    NSLocale *hebrow = [[NSLocale alloc]initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"he_IL"];
    NSDateFormatter *outputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    outputFormatter.locale = hebrow;
    [outputFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
    [outputFormatter setTimeStyle:NSTimeZoneNameStyleShortStandard];
    NSString *outputDate = [outputFormatter stringFromDate:inputDate];
```

The question is: How can I adjust the date format for all of the above?
there is any function or should i do that manually?

thanks in advance!

Comment: The best way is to give the pubDate a single dateFormat, if you can't do so. Write a loop which will keep on trying possible dateFormats till a valid date is formed by dateFormatter.

Comment: yes i know that the best way is to give single dateFormat.
but as i said i've many dateFormat from the parsed xml so i need to find a way to handle them..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an ideal solution, but should work, given the dateString which don't have any information about the timezone is UTC.

```
NSString *dateString = @"11/04/2013 18:10:10";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
NSLocale *enUSPOSIX = [[NSLocale alloc]initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];

[dateFormatter setLocale:enUSPOSIX];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

NSDate *date = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
NSDataDetector *detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeDate
                                                           error:&error];
NSArray *matches = [detector matchesInString:dateString
                                     options:0
                                       range:NSMakeRange(0, [dateString length])];
for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {

    if (match.date) {
        date = match.date;
        break;
    }
}

if (!date) {
    NSArray *dateFormats = @[@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss",
                             @"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm Z",
                             @"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z",
                             @"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"];

    for (NSString *dateFormat in dateFormats) {
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:dateFormat];
        date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
        if (date) {
            break;
        }
    }
}


NSLocale *hebrowLocale = [[NSLocale alloc]initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"he_IL"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:hebrowLocale];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

NSString *formattedDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"DateString : %@",formattedDateString);
```

Comment: thank you.. im already did somethink like that.. 
but this format : yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss
not working.. any ideas?

Comment: @OshriALM I posted the code after testing, it is working for all the formats you mentioned. Can you provide what was the dateString when it failed.

Comment: when im debuging i can see that the string comes from the xml is: "2013-04-17T13:11:44.0/n" i dont know where the '/n' comes from..
but its return nil

Comment: @OshriALM can you change the format to yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.s

Comment: already tried it, not working..
maybe the '/n' its the problem.

Comment: @OshriALM I have included a dataDetector can you check if this is working.

Comment: still now working O_O
im now have one more problem, all the date that actually works they +1 hour..
how can i fix that?
i tried to change the time zone but its now working..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28379/discussion-between-anupdas-and-oshrialm)